# Can't connect to SQL Server anymore after adding an ODBC source

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc

I can't connect to my SQL Server 2008 R2 database after having created a ODBC connector to that particular database! I can't connect neither using SQL Server Management Studio nor Toad.

I'm 100% sure that the misconnection is due to the new ODBC. Meanwhile the ODBC itself works fine! I can connect through it. But if I delete it, the connection isn't brought back.

Comment: I finally succeed in connecting entering the server's IP instead of its DNS. It seems that the addition of the OBDC introduce some mess in the DNSs. I've looked in the Registries (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>ODBC>ODBC.ini>ODBC FILE DNS) but the specified file in my case (C:\Program Files\Common Files\ODBC\Data Sources) is empty...

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, you might try creating an alias name on your computer that points to the IP address.

You could do this in your hosts file.  You can also do this using SQL Server Configuration Manager.  Open your local node > SQL Native Client X Config (32 bit) > Aliases > New...

Give it a name, different from the actual sql name, a port if it's a named instance and then in the server field, put the IP address.